# Get last DIV paragraph content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need output as "Order 4" .

Requirement: I will have many DIVs for each "order" which may or not have paragraph tag . I want to fetch last DIV of paragraph tag that contains "class3".

In below HTML, there are only 4 orders, in future DIV sections may increase means it may extends up to 10 or 20. If last(10 or 20) DIV tag does not contains paragraph tag. i have to show alert with some message else i have to show  order number ex: Order 10. Every paragraph tag must be in DIV that contains "class3" .

Ex: IF 10 DIVs of orders are there. we have only 9 orders and last DIV does not contains paragraph tag , i have to show alert as "No Order"

I must make use of "class1 and class2" in Jquery code.

What am trying is :
At first i am finding last DIV of "class1 class2" whether it contains "class3" or not, If "class3" contains in last DIV, i am trying to get paragraph tag.

How to achieve this?

```js
var lastMessageContent = $('.class1 .class2:last').html();
console.log(lastMessageContent);
//--I am getting last DIV
//var markDownExists = $(this).hasClass("markdown");
//alert(markDownExists);
if ($('.class1').parent().find('.class3').length > 0) {
  // YES, the child element is inside the parent
  console.log("yes")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use the `<>` snippet tool, so we can see how you run your code, current we don't know if you run your jquery when the page is ready or when you click something or another option.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
var $lastPInDiv = $('div > p').last();
if ($lastPInDiv.parent().is(".class3")) console.log("Yes")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution since the op will always be sure to get the last paragraph and no risk to get anything else.

Comment: But, if in last block of div there is no p tag then this solution will not work.

Comment: That depends if the p has to be in the last div or he wants the last p in any div3

Comment: @HareshVidja there is not enough information in the question to justify a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `:last` and `:has()` psudo selectors.

```js
var lastMessageContent= $('.class1:last:has(p)').text();
console.log(lastMessageContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p class="order"> Order 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p class="order"> Order 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p>Order 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked with "var lastMessageContent = $('.class1:last p').html();
console.log(lastMessageContent);"

Comment: Check my edit for best solution... if you get correct solution dont miss for mark as correct and up vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if($('.class2').last().find('.class3').length>0)               //Checks whether last class2 div has class3
    {
           var text = $('.class3').last().find('p').text()         // get class3 p tag text
    }

    else
    {
              alert('Div class3 not present')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code i hope this is help for you

```
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var a = $('.class3').last().find('p').length;
      if(a > 0){
        //  do somthing....
      }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your post.It does'nt seem to answer the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just create code snippet with 3 scenarios, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

**If last order does not contain `<div class"class3">`**.

```js
var lastOrder = $('.class1 .class2:last').children();
if(lastOrder.length) {
    if(lastOrder.children().length) {
        alert(lastOrder.children().text());
    } else {
        alert('No Order');
    }
} else {
    alert('No Order');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

**If last order does not contain `<p>`**.

```js
var lastOrder = $('.class1 .class2:last').children();
if(lastOrder.length) {
    if(lastOrder.children().length) {
        alert(lastOrder.children().text());
    } else {
        alert('No Order');
    }
} else {
    alert('No Order');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**If last order contain `<div class="class3">` and `<p>`**.

```js
var lastOrder = $('.class1 .class2:last').children();
if(lastOrder.length) {
    if(lastOrder.children().length) {
        alert(lastOrder.children().text());
    } else {
        alert('No Order');
    }
} else {
    alert('No Order');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
      <p> Order 4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```